# Redirect User login to diffrent page based on model view id Yii2

Tags: redirect, authentication, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Hello i have question about redirect user after login, im using Yii2 Advanced

the condition is:
1. i have 2 user first user A and user B
2. if i logged as User A it will redirect for example

user A will redirect into ID Employee = 1

> backen/web/index.php?r=Employee%2Fview&id=1

and User b it will redirect into  ID Employee = 2

> backend/web/index.php?r=employee%2Fview&id=2

this is my Login Controller

```
 public function actionLogin() {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->redirect('index.php?r=employee%2Fview&id=2');
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

but all of login user will redirect into View id=2, i really appreaciate any help. Thanks advanced

Comment: You have just put `2` in redirect, so what did you expected?

Comment: hmm okay, how to redirect by get id?

Comment: Emm, put `id` from model instead of `2`?

Comment: would u show me the coding please

Comment: How about you try something?

Comment: `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            if (Yii::$app->user->getId="1") {
                return $this->redirect('index.php?r=karyawan%2Fview&id=1');
            }
        }`
is there something wrong on my code?

Comment: Did you read this? "Emm, put `id` from model instead of `2`"?

Answer (score 1):

If `employee` equal the `user` that is currently logging in, than you have to set the view path accordingly.

```
    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) 
    {
        return $this->redirect(['employee/view', 'id' => $\Yii::$app->user->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

You can [redirect](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#redirect()-detail) wherever you want.